# How to debug simple Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the value of a cell to display as a text that is otherwise merged together under a different cell using formula; the script seems to work but the debug message keeps on popping up, causing the file to crash if tried to many times.

The code I've used is so simple that I can't figure out what's wrong with it...?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  
    Dim Note As Range
    Set Note = Sheets("Interface").Range("D2")

    Sheets("Intake Note").Range("G5").Value = Note
End Sub
```

I expect Cell G5 to have the actual text of whatever is displayed in Cell D2 that was merged together using a formula.

Comment: _"but the debug message keeps on popping up"_ What debug message? What does it say?

Comment: And note that his will run on **any** cell change in the sheet (which makes working on that sheet slower). You should probably use the `worksheet_calculate` event instead. So it only runs if your formulas are recalculating.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, error messge says: Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, the line item that is highlighted is `Set Note = Sheets("Interface").Range("D2")`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, many thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately `worksheet_calculate` was unable to trigger the update. There's not many fields within the box and I'm working with staff that requires as much ergonomic assistance as possible, so I'm happy to sacrifice the speed (at this point in time, it appears to not be noticeable at all, which is really great~ =D) PS, many thanks for fixing up my question~ =D

Comment: @kitarika Please note that `Worksheet_Change` only runs when a **constant value** of a cell changes but it does **not** run when a **formula value** changes! Therefore you might need to switch to the `Worksheet_Calculate` event which runs whenever the sheet is calculated. Also note that `Sheets` and `Worksheets` is not the same `Sheets` can also be a chart sheet (which has no `.Range()`) but `Worksheets` only refers to worksheets. Change `Sheets` into `Worksheets`. • Question 1: Is `Range("G5")` part of a merged cell? • Question 2: In which worksheet is the `Worksheet_Change` event?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, many thanks for explaining the differences. • Question 1: Yes, `Range("G5")` is actually part of a merged range; however when I applied the full range - `Range("G5:G10")` - the error message continued to appear. • Question 2: The `Worksheet_Change` event was coded to `Worksheets("Intake Note")`. I've also changed `Sheets` to `Worksheets` and unfortunately this did not seem to fix the issue either...

Comment: @kitarika That wasn't meant to fix it, just a side note to improve your coding style. See my answer below for the actual issue.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ to give you a bit more background about how the formulae were disbursed, in the `Worksheets("Intake Note")`, there's a set of questions and answers that's made of up free text and formulae within columns B and C. The information is then merged under `Worksheets("Interface")` using formula so that the content can be displayed within 1 cell. Finally, the VBA is to present the content into a free text back under `Worksheets("Intake Note")` so that our staff can double click cell and copy content, as they need to extract html-free value only to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that if this `Worksheet_Change` is in the worksheet `Intake Note` any change in this worksheet will trigger the event again. So this is an endless loop because the event changes a cell … triggers the event, which changes a cell … and so on.

So you need to disable the [Application.EnableEvents property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents) before you change a cell in this event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)  
    Dim Note As Range
    Set Note = Worksheets("Interface").Range("D2")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Worksheets("Intake Note").Range("G5").Value = Note 'this line would trigger another Worksheet_Change event 
    Application.EnableEvents = True 
End Sub
```

But I still believe that you should do all this in the [Worksheet.Calculate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) of the worksheet named `Interface`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
Sheets("Intake Note").Range("G5").Value = Note.Value 
                                                     # instead of:
Sheets("Intake Note").Range("G5").Value = Note
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately it appears that this did not fix the issue...

Comment: @dominique just for your interest the `Range` defaults to `Range.Value` if you don't set it to an object variable. Therefore these lines are exactly the same, the first one is just nicer and more explicit than the second one.